# Wiktionary API to retrieve word forms (or other free service)

Tags: nlp, dictionary, wiktionary

This is a question particularly for Russian/Ukrainian languages but may be useful for other languages too.

Is there a possibility to retrieve word forms as raw data? To use in mobile application for example. These forms are present on the general wiki page. For example [Forms of verb 'to be'](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/be#.D0.9C.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.84.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B8_.D1.81.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BA.D1.81.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.81.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B9.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B0_2). The same you can find for nouns [Noun forms for 'apple' in Russian](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%8F%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE#.D0.9C.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.84.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B8_.D1.81.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BA.D1.81.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.81.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B9.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B0).

I need these forms with description of the form. What I mean is for example:
to be - infinitive; am - first person singular, present time; are - first person plural, present time; etc.

So far I have found that only wiktionary.org provides such information for Russian language. It would be nice if someone could point me to some other services/dictionaries for Russian, Ukrainian and English.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested to use Wiktionary, you can consider [Wikokit](http://code.google.com/p/wikokit/) which is an interface to parsed Wiktionary database.The English and Russian database dumps are available in their download section, but they also provide code/library (Java) for you to create your own database dump. They also provided (I think) the code/library for you to interface with the database, so you no longer have to deal with web services, since you have it running locally.